# count records based on group of interval(days) on date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

**count data between intervals,interval depends on how much older the record**

I have a table called `complaint` in which I have many columns with `ComplaintDate`,I want to show **count of records depends on interval**.

Following interval will be used to categorized records:

1. number of compalaint which is 10 days older.
2. number of compalaint which is 10-20 days older.
3. number of compalaint which is 20-30 days older.
4. number of compalaint which is more than 30 days older.

I have tried something like this

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN ComplaintDate BETWEEN DATEADD (dd,-10,getdate())AND   GETDATE()  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As '0-10',
       SUM(CASE WHEN ComplaintDate BETWEEN  DATEADD (dd,-20,getdate()) AND DATEADD (dd,-10,getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10-20',
       SUM(CASE WHEN ComplaintDate BETWEEN DATEADD (dd,-30,getdate()) AND DATEADD (dd,-20,getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '20-30'       
 FROM Complaint
```

**also i want that day included in 0-10 days interval should not be count in 10-20 or 20-30 days interval and same should apply for other other intervals as well .**

Comment: i dont understand but code formatting not working on my browser for below section. sorry you edited before but i have to edit something and now its again not well formatted

Comment: I've fixed the formatting (it didn't like the indenting space on the sentence "I have tried...")

Comment: Is `ComplaintDate` just dates, or dates and times? And what is the problem with what you've tried?

Comment: its datetime column and i am thinking that instead of making columns of these what i have done, i can use group by interval and then pivot the rows into columns

Comment: whats wrong with your query above?

Comment: @AnandPhadke day included in 0-10 days interval should not be count in 10-20 or 20-30 days interval and same should apply for other other intervals as well

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
SUM(CASE WHEN ComplaintDate > DATEADD (dd,-10,getdate()) AND   ComplaintDate <= GETDATE()  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As '0-10',

SUM(CASE WHEN ComplaintDate > DATEADD (dd,-20,getdate()) AND ComplaintDate<=DATEADD (dd,-10,getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10-20',

SUM(CASE WHEN ComplaintDate > DATEADD (dd,-30,getdate()) AND ComplaintDate <=DATEADD (dd,-20,getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '20-30'    

FROM Complaint
```